# JButton isn't displaying Icon image in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, icons, jbutton

I'm trying to display a .png picture using a GUI.  But I'm having trouble with the pictures displaying. 
I think I've isolated where I'm messing up in my instructions but can't seem to find a working solution.

I am told in my instructions to...

- Set the title to Lab Button
- Create two local variables of type Icon: image1 and image2.
  Initialize them with a new ImageIcon base on Image1 and Image2 - like this:
  Icon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Image1.png"));
- Initialize the field clickImage with a new ImageIcon that is based on Image3
- **Initialize the field imgButton with a new JButton that accepts image1 as the only argument**
- Call the method setRolloverIcon on imgButton and pass image2 as roll-over icon
- Add the imgButton to this (ImageButton, which is a JFrame)

It seems like I need to create a method to initialize imgButton.  But if I did that wouldn't I need to create a new variable for each Icon image?  For instance

```
imgButton = new JButton(image1);
final JButton imgButton2 = new JButton(image2);
final JButton imgButton3 = new JButton(image3);
```

Any help that I can get would be very appreciated.  Thanks.

```
package ImageButton.Downloads;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ImageButton extends JFrame
{


    private final JButton imgButton;
    private final Icon clickImage;

    public ImageButton() 
    {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Lab Button");

        Icon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Image1.png"));
        Icon image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Image2.png"));
        clickImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Image3.gif"));

        imgButton = new JButton(image1);

        imgButton.setRolloverIcon(image2);



    }


}

package ImageButton.Downloads;


import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ImageButtonApp 
{

    public ImageButtonApp() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();

        imageButton.setSize(660, 660);
        imageButton.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        imageButton.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating **two** JFrames, displaying **one** of them but adding your JButton to **none** of them. In other words, your code ignores this rec:

> Add the imgButton to this (ImageButton, which is a JFrame)

Solution: use only **one** JFrame, your class as per your instructions, add your JButton to it or to a JPanel that is added to the JFrame, and display it.

Specifically, change this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // extra JFrame that's never used!
frame.setTitle("Lab Button");
```

to this:

```
super("Lab Button");
```

and add an `add(imgButton);` at the end of the constructor.